# Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined on nested form group in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I keep having an error of "Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined" when creating a validation for my nested group. On the main group, I do not have problems but if it is on the nested form group, that's where the issue comes. Please see my codes below:

```
<form
    [formGroup]="form"
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)"
    class="border border-light p-5"
  >
    <div class="form-group">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Plaza Name"
        formControlName="name"
        id="name"
        class="form-control mb-4"
        mdbInput
        required
      />
      <span
        *ngIf="formHasError('name', 'required') && isSubmitted"
        style="color: red;"
      >
        Plaza Name is required
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Plaza Code"
        formControlName="code"
        id="code"
        class="form-control mb-4"
        mdbInput
        required
      />
      <span
        *ngIf="formHasError('code', 'required') && isSubmitted"
        style="color: red;"
      >
        Plaza code is required
      </span>
    </div>

    <div formGroupName="lanes">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="Lane Number"
          formControlName="number"
          id="number"
          class="form-control mb-4"
          mdbInput
          required
        />
        <span
          *ngIf="formHasError('lanes.number', 'required') && isSubmitted"
          style="color: red;"
        >
          Lane number is required
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select
          formControlName="type"
          id="type"
          class="browser-default custom-select mb-4"
          mdbInput
          required
        >
          <option *ngFor="let type of typeSelect" [value]="type.label">{{
            type.label
          }}</option>
        </select>
        <!-- <span
          *ngIf="formHasError('lanes.type', 'required') && isSubmitted"
          style="color: red;"
        >
          Select a lane type
        </span> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <button
      mdbBtn
      color="info"
      outline="true"
      block="true"
      class="z-depth-0 my-4 waves-effect"
      mdbWavesEffect
      type="submit"
    >
      Send
    </button>
 </form>
```

This is in the ts file

```
createForm() {
    this.form =  this.fb.group({
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      code: [null, Validators.required],
      lanes: this.fb.group({
        number: [null, Validators.required],
        type: [null, Validators.required]
      })
    });
}

formHasError(controlName: string, errorName: string) {
   return this.form.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
}
```

Can you please show me how to do this right? THank you.

Comment: use `this.form.get(controlName).hasError(errorName)` NOT this.form.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName), see e.g. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufuc3j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Eliseo Your suggestion works but I get an error of "Object is possibly 'null'"

Comment: well, you can make in two steps, I updated the stackblitz, and put as answer

Comment: when did you run the `createForm` method ?

Comment: I found out why it 's not working you just need to use get method instead of bracket notation 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufuc3j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
formHasError(controlName: string, errorName: string) {
    const control=this.form.get(controlName);
    return control?control.hasError(errorName):false;
  }
```

Comment: but in this case nested controls in the formgroup will keep return false 

Comment: my stackblitz works :( . What version of angular has you used?

Answer (score 2):

Personally; I opt for such a solution it's easier and clearer without using an extra function

```
<form
    [formGroup]="form"
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)"
    class="border border-light p-5"
  >
    <div class="form-group">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Plaza Name"
        formControlName="name"
        id="name"
        class="form-control mb-4"
        mdbInput
        required
      />
      <span
        *ngIf="form.name.hasError('required') && isSubmitted"
        style="color: red;"
      >
        Plaza Name is required
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Plaza Code"
        formControlName="code"
        id="code"
        class="form-control mb-4"
        mdbInput
        required
      />
      <span
        *ngIf="form.code.hasError('required') && isSubmitted"
        style="color: red;"
      >
        Plaza code is required
      </span>
    </div>

    <div formGroupName="lanes">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="Lane Number"
          formControlName="number"
          id="number"
          class="form-control mb-4"
          mdbInput
          required
        />
        <span
          *ngIf="form.lanes.number.hasError('required') && isSubmitted"
          style="color: red;"
        >
          Lane number is required
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select
          formControlName="type"
          id="type"
          class="browser-default custom-select mb-4"
          mdbInput
          required
        >
          <option *ngFor="let type of typeSelect" [value]="type.label">{{
            type.label
          }}</option>
        </select>
        <!-- <span
          *ngIf="formHasError('lanes.type', 'required') && isSubmitted"
          style="color: red;"
        >
          Select a lane type
        </span> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <button
      mdbBtn
      color="info"
      outline="true"
      block="true"
      class="z-depth-0 my-4 waves-effect"
      mdbWavesEffect
      type="submit"
    >
      Send
    </button>
 </form>
```

Comment: what is the relationship with my answer?

Comment: the get method allow to get a control by path this `form.lanes.number.hasError('required')`    `form.get('lanes.number').hasError('required')`

Comment: I like you statement **easier and clearer without using an extra function** 

Comment: ah, yes using get is much better :)

Answer (score 1):

cause you have a formgroup (lanes) in your main form so if you call `this.form.controls['lanes']` it will return you a formGroup with controls not a formcontrol so you should consider your child form in your function and your formHasError should be:

```
if(this.form.controls[controlName].controls) {
        return this.form.controls[controlName]['controls'].hasError(errorName);
    } else {
        return this.form.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
    }
```

Comment: See my comment. In general is better aproach using this.form.get(controlName) than this.form.controls[controlName].

Comment: @Eliseo yes it's better but the way using controls will be like this.

Comment: @Eliseo Your suggestion works but I get an error of "Object is possibly 'null'" but it does the trick. I'll have a problem when compiling it for distribution.

Comment: @FatemeFazli check my answer I don't know this before we pass this `lanes.number` for path to `get` method  this will be a big change for me 

Comment: @malbarmawi yes you are right, I didn't know either 

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use `get` method

```
formHasError(controlName: string, errorName: string) : boolean {
   return this.form.get(controlName).hasError(errorName);
}
```

> [get](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get) method retrieves a child control given the control's name or path.

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrhtnv)